# Inserting variables as command arguments in a bash script

Tags: bash

I have a file for screencasting on linux, and I want to modify parts of it based on user input. At the moment I can't even get it to stick an argument in a command from a variable.

```
#!/bin/bash -x

fps="30"
capturesize="hd1080"
outputsize="720"

filter=-vf 'scale=${outputsize}'

avconv \
-f x11grab -r $fps -s $capturesize -i :0.0 \
-f alsa -ac 2 -i pulse \
-f alsa -ac 2 -i pulse \
-f alsa -ac 1 -i pulse \
-map 0:0 -map 1:0 -map 2:0 -map 3:0 \
-vcodec libx264 \
$filter \
-pre:v lossless_ultrafast \
-acodec libmp3lame \
-threads 4 \
-y $@
```

`$fps` and `$capturesize` are evaluated properly but `$filter` assignment gives a nice little:

```
+ filter=-vf
+ 'scale=${outputsize}'
~/bin/screencap: line 9: scale=${outputsize}: command not found
```

Changing the line to:

```
filter="-vf 'scale=$outputsize'"
```

Gives an even less pleasant:

```
+ filter='-vf '\''scale=720'\'''
+ avconv -f x11grab [...] -vf ''\''scale=720'\''' [...]
[...]
No such filter: 'scale=720'
Error opening filters!
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an array. It has the added benefit of protecting items that contain spaces, something
you can't do if you try to store it in a space-separated list.

```
#!/bin/bash -x

fps="30"
capturesize="hd1080"
outputsize="720"

filter=( -vf "scale=${outputsize}" )

avconv \
-f x11grab -r "$fps" -s "$capturesize" -i :0.0 \
-f alsa -ac 2 -i pulse \
-f alsa -ac 2 -i pulse \
-f alsa -ac 1 -i pulse \
-map 0:0 -map 1:0 -map 2:0 -map 3:0 \
-vcodec libx264 \
"${filter[@]}" \
-pre:v lossless_ultrafast \
-acodec libmp3lame \
-threads 4 \
-y "$@"
```

You can put all the options in a single array; a small example:

```
options=( -f x11grab -r "$fps" -s "$capturesize" )
options+=( -i :0.o )
# etc
avconv "${options[@]}" -y "$@"
```

Comment: This... Works. I don't know why or how but when spaces are inserted into the vf value it adds quotes automatically!... Bash seems to be very unpredictable, glad SO is so full of bash masters :P

Comment: When an array is expanded *in quotes* using the `[@]` index operator, each element of the array is quoted so it is treated as a single word.

Answer (score 0):

```
filter="-vf scale=${outputsize}"
```

Comment: The result should be: `-vf 'scale=720'` - yours doesn't have the single quotes.